# umbraco razor macro adding extra return in html output

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

I have a macro call in my masterpage that sets the body class depending on a number of factors (depth, URL path, etc) However, I've stripped it down to find out why the macro is adding an extra space in the final html.

masterpage macro line:

```
    <body class="<umbraco:Macro Alias="Bodyclass" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>">
```

Simplified macro:

```
@{
  var bodyClass = "";
  if ((Model.NodeTypeAlias == "WLHomePage" ) ||
     (Model.NodeTypeAlias == "WLHomeSubPage" ))
  { bodyClass = "front"; } else {
     bodyClass = "not-front";  }
    @bodyClass;
}
```

Returns:

```
    <body class="
front">
```

Note the extra space between the first doublequote of the class=" and the actual class string.

Comment: strange. i do this exact same thing (to add a custom className to the body tag) all the time and haven't had any problems with extra whitespace. Perhaps something else in your macro that you are not showing may be at fault? (Although one difference is I don't have the semi-colon after where the @bodyClass is finally output.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove Extra Newlines**

Ensure that you don't have an extra new line before or after your macro code. You may want to open the cshtml file in a text editor to check that. After doing some testing on my end (using v4.8) that's the only condition I can find in which the extra newline is added. Using razor comments (`@* ... *@`) before the code will also add a newline.

---

**Alternative**

Another alternative for adding the class to the tag could be writing the tag out with razor, like so:

```
<umbraco:Macro language="cshtml" runat="server">
@{
    string bodyClass = "not-front";

    if ((Model.NodeTypeAlias == "WLHomePage" ) ||
        (Model.NodeTypeAlias == "WLHomeSubPage" ))
    {
        bodyClass = "front";
    }

    @:<body class="@bodyClass">
}
</umbraco:Macro>

    ...

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
    if (Model.NodeTypeAlias == "WLHomePage" || Model.NodeTypeAlias == "WLHomeSubPage")
    { 
        return "front";
    }
    else 
    {
        return "not-front";
    }
}
```

Try it where it just returns a value instead.

Comment: Rasmus Fjord: thanks. I had that thought, too. I tried that already, whatever is adding the return merely adds it at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Html.Raw to output the html.
So something like:

```
@{
  var bodyClass = "";
  if(...)
  { 
    bodyClass = "front"; 
  } 
  else 
  {
    bodyClass = "not-front";  
  }

  @(Html.Raw(@bodyClass));

}
```

Comment: cast01 thanks, but I tried that, before and just now. Same result. Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

My fellow .NET developer cracked this one: It's the white space in the first line. Move the var up, like so:

```
   @{ var bodyClass = "";
```

and >poof< whitespace gone.

So is this an umbraco bug?

Thanks all!